# apt update error after installing python3.7 in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt, python

```
Start-Date: 2019-11-15  23:47:32
Commandline: apt install python3.7
Requested-By: my_name (1000)

Install: libpython3.7-minimal:amd64 (3.7.3-2~18.04.1, automatic), python3.7:amd64 (3.7.3-2~18.04.1), libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 (3.7.3-2~18.04.1, automatic), python3.7-minimal:amd64 (3.7.3-2~18.04.1, automatic)
End-Date: 2019-11-15  23:47:40
```

After doing the above, there is a strange negative(-) sign on the top-right menu that says "A problem occurred when checking for updates" and `sudo apt update` gives me following error:

```
sh: 1: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Moreover, I removed python3.7 and then when I tried to do `$ python3` in bash it gives me: `bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

But when I do `$ python3.6`, it gives me the interpreter of python3.6. `$ python2` also works fine.
Please help me solve this issue. I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to install the official python3 package.

```
sudo apt install python3
```

Depeding on your Ubuntu version this is.

19.04  - python 3.7.1 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/python/python3)
18.04  - python 3.6.5 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python/python3)
16.04  - python 3.5

---

To fix issue:

> /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter

create symlink like this:

```
sudo ln -s python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

---

There're (PPA) repositories/sources which allow you to install programms on ubuntu distributions missing them - like universe/multiverse or deadsnakes ppa for python 3.8 or 3.7. These inofficial packages are provided by community members and could lead to further trouble eg. when installing official python3-module packages along with ppa python3 (see. Third Party Modules notice:   https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Installing deadsnakes ppa and python3.(7|8) is easy

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install python3.7 python3.7-dev
```

Comment: python3 problem is solved but I am still getting the apt error. But now it also gives ModeuleNotFound: No module named 'apt-pkg'

Comment: that's a new question. please accept answer (tick it) - first search - then ask new ones. I'd take "This happened to me on Ubuntu 18.04.2 after I tried to install Python3.7 from the deadsnakes repo." from here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg